# Bluetooth Cassette Adapter with Long Battery Life

Tags: audio, bluetooth, audio-adapters

I've been looking for an inexpensive device to get my car to play songs from my phone.  I've got a wired cassette adapter, but the wires inevitably break (I have a teen that uses it too).  I found this [bluetooth cassette adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HKN4MOU), but it's $60 and only lasts 8 hours per charge.

Is there an adapter that lasts for at least 15 hours of playback for less than $40, perhaps one that uses the cassette spindle drive to augment (or replace) the battery altogether?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here since you have a cassette player, but does your car have a radio? If so, there are plenty of great phone accessories for locally broadcasting to your car's radio

Comment: I've used several of those without good results, even when wired (or directly attached) to the phone.  The signal just doesn't come through clearly on the radio.  Cassette adapters generally have a static-free signal transfer, but have those fragile wires. I'm hoping that Bluetooth does better transferring the signal without static than FM radio because Bluetooth is digital, whereas FM is analog.  I realize that doesn't always fix the problem, but I've had good luck with Bluetooth indoors and am hoping that kind of good signal transfer works in the car too.

Comment: I know this is not what you are looking for, however I have been using an AUX Bluetooth adapter for some time with good quality audio. Sadly a lot of radios don't have an AUX (3.5mm) input port. :\

Comment: Yes, that has bothered me ever since I started driving. (I have yet to own a car with one).